# Динамическая загрузка списка по выбору из другого списка mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax

Добрый день. Не могу справиться с задачкой в MVC. Есть четыре списка и их нужно связать. То есть выбрав в первом списке что-то, формируем второй и так далее.
Схема "Страна-город-район-улица". Использовала схему в ajax запросом и частичными представлениями. Связку двух первых списков выполняем, но как только второй список сформирован, и выбрав из него чтото третий список не формирует.

```
$('#state').change(function()
{
   // получаем выбранный id
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetItems44")/' + id, 
        success: function (data) {
            // заменяем содержимое присланным частичным представлением
            $('#city').replaceWith(data);
        }
    });
});

$('#city').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetItemsTopic")/' + id,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#punkt').replaceWith(data);
        }
    });
});

$('#punkt').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetItemsTopic2")/' + id,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#street').replaceWith(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

В нем в первый get заходит, а во второй уже нет.

Comment: Согласно [документации](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/), `The .replaceWith() method removes all data and event handlers associated with the removed nodes.` Вот тут-то собака и порылась.

Comment: Можно мне разъяснить, ибо там я была и немного не улавливаю что сделать?? Чем можно заменить  .replaceWith()  или как можно донести список полученного до след. списка???

Comment: при вызове `$('#city').replaceWith(data);` установленный ранее обработчик события `onchange` сбрасывается. Соответственно, надо или использовать какой-либо иной способ заполнения нужного элемента полученными данными, либо устанавливать обработчик непосредственно после вызова `replaceWith()`

Comment: А какие элементы вы можете посоветовать? Я не сильна в скриптах. Заранее очень благодарна, но можно как то примером показать что и как? :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Навскидку, если изменить код примерно так, то должно заработать:

```
$('#state').change(function()
{
    // получаем выбранный id
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetItems44")/' + id, 
        success: function (data) {
            // заменяем содержимое присланным частичным представлением
            $('#city').replaceWith(data);
            $('#city').change(function () {
                var id = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetItemsTopic")/' + id,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#punkt').replaceWith(data);
                        $('#punkt').change(function () {
                            var id = $(this).val();
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'GET',
                                url: '@Url.Action("GetItemsTopic2")/' + id,
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $('#street').replaceWith(data);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Однако предупреждаю, что с JQuery я дела практически не имел, так что возможны нюансы. :)

В целом же проблема заключается в том, что Вы сначала устанавливаете обработчики событий на элементы `city` и `punkt`, а после этого при изменении 'state' отрабатывает вызов `$('#city').replaceWith(data);`, который полностью заменяет элемент `city`, сбрасывая установленный ранее обработчик.
Соответственно, один из вариантов (см. предложенный вариант кода) — это сделать так, чтобы обработчики устанавливались после вызова `replaceWith()`. Тут, само собой, предполагается, что в `data` возвращается элемент с `id="city"`, иначе ничего работать не будет. :)

Ну и еще этот вариант кода предполагает, что селекты изменяются строго поочередно, и нельзя пропустить выбор `state`, начав сразу с `city`.

Comment: Все заработало!!! Вы не представляете, как меня спасли =)) Огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: Добрый вечер, возникла небольшая проблема. Выбрала я все списки, в post в контроллере передаются id выбранных из списка пунктов, но как только сохранило все, страница обновилась и все что было внесено остается в заполненных полях, все кроме тех полей к которому я применила эту связку. Как быть?? Как вывести то что выбрано в списка с связкой?

Answer (score 0):

Повесьте обработчик события на весь документ - тогда события на элементах изменяемых аяксом будут отрабатывать как надо, например:

```
$(document).on('событие', 'селектор', function () {
//Код
});
```